# Smooth scroll URL issues from one page to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I am using GSAP. I am getting the issue on the smooth scroll.

I have two pages. `home.php` and `aboutus.php`. I have one menu and I am adding dynamically on all the pages.

I am on the home page and if I click on `contactus` then smooth scroll is working and my URL is `http://localhost:8080/example/smoth1.php#contactus`

Now my issue is, I am on `aboutus` page and when I click on `contactus` i am getting the URL `http://localhost:8080/example/aboutus.php#contactus`

It's not redirecting on the homepage because I have contactus section on the home page.

I tried `<li><a href="smoth1.php#contactus">Contactus</a></li>` but then my smothscroll not wokring.

Would you help me out in this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var controller1 = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
  controller1.scrollTo(function(target) {
    TweenMax.to(window, 3, {
      scrollTo: {
        y: target - 65, // scroll position of the target along y axis
        autoKill: true, // allows user to kill scroll action smoothly
      },
      ease: Cubic.easeInOut
    });
  });
  //  Bind scroll to anchor links
  $(document).on("click", ".smothscrollclass a[href^='#']", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    if ($(id).length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // trigger scroll
      controller1.scrollTo(id);
      // If supported by the browser we can also update the URLï»¿
      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        history.pushState("", document.title, id);
      }

    };
  });

});
```

```css
.col1 {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="main_list smothscrollclass">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contactus">Contactus</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php">Aboutus</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col1" id="home">
  <h2>Home</h2>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>


</div>

<div class="col2" id="contactus">
  <h2>Contactus</h2>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>


</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe a type but you need a # in front of aboutus <li><a href="#aboutus.php">Aboutus</a></li>

Comment: @jeff, If I add # then I am getting the URL http://localhost:8080/example/smoth1.php#aboutus.php     which is wrong. About us is my new page.